# Hexagon packing algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, packing

I'm trying to pack hexagons, within bigger hexagons, as shown here:

[image]

For this example, I have 5 "children" to put in my "father" hexagon.

Each time I've got too many children, I would like to reduce the size (divide by 3?) of the children, to store more of them, as shown on this image (ignore the bad position quality):

[image]

Have you ever worked on this kind of problem? Is there any algorithm I could use to determine for a given hexagon size, the position for each new hexagon?

I've seen a lot of these algorithms for circle packing, but nothing for hexagon packing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to generate a hexagonal grid with coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734438/algorithm-to-generate-a-hexagonal-grid-with-coordinate-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found exactly what I was looking for on this topic:
[Algorithm to generate a hexagonal grid with coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734438/algorithm-to-generate-a-hexagonal-grid-with-coordinate-system#20735492)

Thanks to the link above, here is the algorithm I used to generate a grid, `itemCount` is the number of hexes you need to put on your grid.

`this.x` and `this.y` are the origin of the main hex.
`this.radius` is the radius of the main hex, in px.

```
generateHexGrid(itemCount) {
  let size = 0;
  let pushed = 0;

  /*
  `n` must be odd

    n | columns-per row sequence
    --+-------------------------
    3 | 2 3 2
    5 | 3 4 5 4 3
    7 | 4 5 6 7 6 5 4
    9 | 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5
    */

  // This can be optimised to make it generic if you need more hexes
  if (itemCount <= 7) {
    size = 3;
  } else if (itemCount <= 19) {
    size = 5;
  } else if (itemCount <= 37) {
    size = 7;
  } else if (itemCount <= 61) {
    size = 9;
  }
  const radius = this.radius / size;
  const toReturn = [];
  const ang30 = 30 * (Math.PI/180);
  const xOff = Math.cos(ang30) * (radius);
  const yOff = Math.sin(ang30) * (radius);
  const half = Math.floor(size / 2);

  for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    const cols = size - Math.abs(row - half);

    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      const x = Math.ceil(this.x + xOff * (col * 2 + 1 - cols));
      const y = Math.ceil(this.y + yOff * (row - half) * 3);
      toReturn.push({
        x,
        y,
        radius,
      });
      pushed ++;
      if (pushed === itemCount) {
        return toReturn;
      }
    }
  }
  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24155049)

Comment: Sure sorry, let me update my answer